# Asymptotics of the Fourier transform of a non-analytic function involving an exponential

Tags: asymptotics, fourier-transform

While reading  [this](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/42290654/Stationary_states_of_non-linear_oscillat20160207-22903-1gvl1y5.pdf?1454845960=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DStationary_states_of_non_linear_oscillat.pdf&Expires=1602699031&Signature=GH2DMaCPzsrQLI9-jPvATYHNlpmg2F542H4N-VBEC3DE4tMKR08uOpPqOdUxGFBbuxsvOgnWii%7EuD2xqEnGFWEg9Qg%7E1-lDGVIfQaAMzcxrL3WJaXn3eE-fc7wUrtETYF0wqM-GL1j1igtejoHJywwN9JfjYdE71%7E-2LK6fhQFSq-vLQvfDX3%7Eg2RvrhNf031m5yU1BcL8XDwLnoSz1O8bdeaqAlWjlQiX6C2tOUFHhdBXxLvnT1vy4-f1u2quX6cHgw1DOx3SG9ewd8hjkKbQt0-MJGYXiATHHSu3hx8tL1V%7ELWAwWMLip4XhJYXHahrdjoKh-E%7E6S8g%7EhQYKIsyg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) article, the I was puzzled by the following statement, used several times in the article. Consider a function $f(x)$ whose Fourier transform is
$$
\hat{f}(k) = \exp\left(-c {|k|^\alpha}\right),
$$

for some $c>0$. Then the author claims that, "The asymptotics at large x are determined by the first non-analytical term in the series expansion of the exponent", which is $c|k|^\alpha$.

**Can anyone tell me where this comes from?** No sources are cited for this step in the paper.

The author then goes on to write
$$ 
f(|x|\to \infty) \approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty -c |k|^\alpha \exp(ikx) \frac{dk}{2\pi},
$$
which of course is not defined as such, but he uses Abel summation in the form
$$
\int_0^\infty \exp(-it)t^{\alpha+2m} dt = (-1)^{m+1} i e^{-i(\alpha \pi/2)} \Gamma(\alpha+2m+1),
$$
to conclude that
$$
f(|x|\to \infty) \approx \frac{const.}{|x|^{\alpha+1}},
$$
with $const. = \frac{c}{\alpha} \sin(\pi\alpha/2)\Gamma(\alpha)/\pi$. Can anyone explain to me what is going on in the first step where the approximation happens? I'm willing to put up with the ill-defined integral in the second step if I can understand that.

Answer (score 1):

For $c >0,\alpha > 0, \alpha\not \in 2 \Bbb{Z}$, $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \phi \ge 0,\hat{\phi}(0)=1$, $m\alpha> n > \alpha + 1$, $\hat{\phi}^{(l)}(0)=0$ for $1\le l\le n$, as $x\to \infty$, due to the decay of the Fourier transform of  $C^n(\Bbb{R})$ functions whose derivatives are integrable $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c |k|^\alpha} e^{ikx}dk = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c |k|^\alpha} \hat{\phi}(k) e^{ikx}dk+O(x^{-n})$$ $$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_{l=1}^m \frac{(-c |k|^\alpha)^l}{l!} \hat{\phi}(k) e^{ikx}dk+O(x^{-n})$$

With the convolution theorem
$$ = \sum_{l=1}^m \frac{(-c)^l}{l!} \phi\ast \mathcal{F}^{-1}[|k|^{\alpha l}](x)+O(x^{-n})$$

With a bit of complex analysis and theory of distributions we get that for $x\ne 0$, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[|k|^{\alpha l}](x)$ has a closed-form $=h(\alpha l) |x|^{-\alpha l-1}$ so that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c |k|^\alpha} e^{ikx}dk =\sum_{l=1}^m \frac{(-c)^l}{l!} \phi\ast h(\alpha l) |x|^{-\alpha l-1} + O(x^{-n})$$
$$= \sum_{l=1}^m \frac{(-c)^l}{l!} h(\alpha l) (|x|^{-\alpha l-1}+O(x^{-\alpha l-2})) + O(x^{-n})$$